# Firestore filter error: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: security, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, rules

I'm working on a Firestore database with an Ionic cordova Client. Here is my data structure :

[image]

I would like to filter my designs collection based on the ownerId field.

I tried several rules but all gave me the

> Error : Missing or insufficient permissions.

Here is my current rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /designs/{design} {
      allow read: if resource.data.ownerId == request.auth.uid ;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my client code

```
AngularFirestore.collection(`designs`).snapshotChanges().map(x => {
            return x.map(y => {
              return y.payload.doc.data() ;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that rules cannot be used as filters.

If you try and read a single document, where `ownerId == request.auth.id` then it will work.

If you want to list all of the documents which are readable by this user, then you'll need to filter based on the current user ID (shown here as userId):

```
AngularFirestore.collection(`designs`).where('ownerId', '==', userId).snapshotChanges().map(x => {
            return x.map(y => {
              return y.payload.doc.data() ;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Omg, I've just spent 2 hours investigating this!